# Select form within CSS menu losing focus of CSS dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a css dropdown menu with an HTML select form inside of that CSS menu. I have noticed, in firefox only, that when I am hovering on the CSS menu and I click on the select dropdown button, the whole CSS menu loses hover focus, causing the whole CSS menu to disappear. Any thoughts?

jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/jKV8Z/1

```
<div class="popup-button">
 <div class="popup-container">
  <span class="popup-title">Title:</span>
   <select>
   <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
   <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>


.popup-button {
    background: #000;
    float: left;
    padding: 6px 0 7px;
    position: relative;
    width: 148px;
}
.popup-container {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    left: 148px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}


$('.popup-button').live('hover', function(){
 $(this).children('.popup-container').toggle();
});
```

Comment: This is not a real question. You need to show the code you have so far; otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Code Sample? jsFiddle link? Link to your site? There really is nothing to help with at this point.

Comment: A "HTML select element within the dropdown", really? :D A `<select>` _is_ a dropdown. A select element has `<option>`s (which map to values).

Comment: @Rob: If this doesn't get reopened then you might want to open this as a new question with code. It'll be useful to link to http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/jKV8Z/1/ as well which is a working example of your code. JSFiddle is a useful tool to use for any HTML/CSS/JS question since people can see an immediate example of the issues and have the ability to quickly play with it to try out solutions.

Comment: @Chris: It's a bad idea to repost questions no matter what happens. Questions that aren't getting reopen votes should be flagged for mod attention instead.

Comment: @BoltClock: OK. Duly noted. Didn't realise that was the kind of thing that should be flagged for. Makes sense though I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some troubleshooting, I decided to just get rid of the jQuery hover event since there wasn't any animation and control the CSS menu with just a :hover. That took care of the firefox issue.

```
.popup-button:hover .popup-container {
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this in pure CSS, so no JavaScript is needed.

The new CSS pseudo-class `:focus-within` would help for cases like this and will help with accessibility when people use tabbing for navigating, common when using screen readers.

```
.popup-button:focus-within .popup-container,
.popup-button:hover .popup-container {
  display: block;
}
```

---

> The :focus-within pseudo-class matches elements that either themselves
>   match :focus or that have descendants which match :focus.

You can check which browsers support this http://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within